# Get Undefined variable in Laravel blade when using PHP-FPM

Tags: php, laravel, fpm

I have some variables in my blade files, These variables may be empty so I use `or` when I trying to echo the variable .

like this:

```
<div style="background-color: {{ $color or '#888' }}">
```

but when I run my application I got this error:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: color
```

I searched in internet and found for checking the variables I should use `or` but I don't know why I got error !!

P.S: This code run on my previous server without any problem, but in new server I have this error ! previous server was Apache+PHP 7.2 and the new server is Nginx+PHP-FPM .

Answer (score 1):

The variable has to exist at least in order for that check to work. 
You can try this:

```
{{ isset($color) ?: '#888' }}
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I said this code worked on my previous server, I think I need some change in php configuration

Comment: I tried your code on my local machine, I have PHP 7.1.19 and it doesn't work, it throws the same error.

Comment: Reading further here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php 
?? will work without a isset check, but the or is equal to || check which checks just for boolean values, not if something exists or not. So I doubt that your code worked if the variable wasn't passed to the view at all.

Comment: But according to this document : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data we can use `or` for checking the variable

Comment: This may be due to PHP version requirements. In older versions such comparison is possible, while in later it may not be. Besides, the documentation may not have it right - this is best tested in the current version of PHP.

Comment: Yeah, and that depends which version of laravel you use. Because the blade `or` logical operator got removed: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade